# How to convert Magick::Image from ImageMagick 7 to QImage?

Tags: imagemagick

This was a quite easy task in `ImageMagick 6`, just `getConstPixels()`, `ColorRGB` and you are done.

But I'm unable to do the same task with `ImageMagick 7`, I got an ugly mostly pink something.

What am I doing wrong?

```cpp
QImage
convert( const Magick::Image & img )
{
    QImage qimg( static_cast< int > ( img.columns() ),
        static_cast< int > ( img.rows() ), QImage::Format_RGB888 );
    using Quantum = MagickCore::Quantum;
    const Quantum * pixels;

    for( int y = 0; y < qimg.height(); ++y)
    {
        pixels = img.getConstPixels( 0, y, static_cast< std::size_t > ( qimg.width() ), 1 );

        for( int x = 0; x < qimg.width(); ++x )
        {
            int red = 0;
            int green = 0;
            int blue = 0;

            if( MagickCore::GetPixelRedTraits( img.constImage() ) )
                red = ( (double) GetPixelRed( img.constImage(), pixels ) /
                    (double) QuantumRange ) * 255;

            if( MagickCore::GetPixelGreenTraits( img.constImage() ) )
                green = ( (double) GetPixelGreen( img.constImage(), pixels ) /
                    (double) QuantumRange ) * 255;

            if( MagickCore::GetPixelBlueTraits( img.constImage() ) )
                blue = ( (double) GetPixelBlue( img.constImage(), pixels ) /
                    (double) QuantumRange ) * 255;

            qimg.setPixel( x, y, QColor( red, green, blue ).rgb() );

            pixels += MagickCore::GetPixelChannels( img.constImage() );
        }
    }

    return qimg;
}
```

Thank you.

[image: Source image] - Source image.

[image: Result] - Result.

As I can guess, in `ImageMagick 7` something wrong with touching pixel by `X, Y`. Am I right?

Comment: It would seem that one of your methods has changed in Imagemagick 7.  Have you checked the documentation.  Sorry, I do not code Imagemagick.

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue why the above code doesn't work, but I found a following solution:

```cpp
QImage
convert( const Magick::Image & img )
{
    QImage qimg( static_cast< int > ( img.columns() ),
        static_cast< int > ( img.rows() ), QImage::Format_ARGB32 );

    for( int y = 0; y < qimg.height(); ++y )
    {
        for( int x = 0; x < qimg.width(); ++x )
        {
            Magick::PixelInfo p = img.pixelColor( x, y );

            qimg.setPixel( x, y, QColor( MagickCore::ScaleQuantumToChar( p.red ),
                MagickCore::ScaleQuantumToChar( p.green ),
                MagickCore::ScaleQuantumToChar( p.blue ),
                MagickCore::ScaleQuantumToChar( p.alpha ) ).rgba() );
        }
    }

    return qimg;
}
```